# To do list for UDP based Asteroids game

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, network-protocols

I am developing the protocol for my network Asteroids game. The first version will just allow each player have a ship shooting opponents in a scrolling world. Later I will add rocks, many rocks.

It seems non trivial to implement the protocol on top of UDP, however UDP is unquestionably the way to go in real time games. I have studied Gaffers articles on networking for games and so I think I will have to implement the following on top of UDP:

- Reliablilty (making sure certain packets arrive by sending
  acknowledgments. This implies also making sure that the
  acknowledgements arrive).
- Fragmentation and reassembly of packets that are larger than the
  recommended UDP packet size.
- Detecting dead clients.

Have I left anything major out?

Comment: How will you ensure acknowledgements arrive ?

Comment: Do you care about out of order arrivals?

Comment: @awoodland In the case of some messages order may be important. In others, out of order messages are discarded.

Comment: @cnicutar there is a very good treatment of this in <http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/reliability-and-flow-control/>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, will you simply end up re-inventing TCP / stream socket functionality? Once you start considering ACK/NAK, packet ordering and re-assembly, and endpoint integrity, you're essentially re-inventing the wheel. Not only that, but you're doing it in user space, and without the extensive path optimizations and memory management strategies provided by the kernel. I'm not saying UDP is the wrong choice, but have a look at the source for multiplayer / network code in the Q3 engine, etc. A lot depends on payload contents and redundancy. i.e., can you afford to drop frames / packets?

Comment: For some packets, it is OK to take the latest updates and ignore lost or out of order packets. For certain packets, they must be delivered or resent if not acked. I realize this in reinventing the wheel. I don't mind too much as this is a hobby thing.